# What is the point of absolute value squared in wave function's probability density?

Tags: wave-equation

The wave function is defined as $$ \Psi(x,t) $$
To get the probability, they squared it with a modulus bracket $$ |\Psi(x,t)|^2 $$ Because amplitude can also be `-ve` but the probability cannot be. My question is, What is the actual point of both mod and squaring together?

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind  $$ |\Psi(x,t)|^2 = \Psi(x,t)^*\Psi(x,t)$$

Where $*$ indicates complex conjugacy. So the modulus is guaranteed to be real by this definition of the inner product.

The modulus indicates the probability density, the chance of finding the particle between $x$ and $x+dx$.

Comment: Why is there an integral there? The absolute value of $\Psi$ is just $\sqrt{\Psi^*\Psi}$

Comment: Bas habit. Fixed. Thanks!

Comment: That's right. An integral arises if one wants to calculate the probability that a particle is located in a set $\Omega$ at time $t$. $P=\int_{\Omega}|\Psi(x,t)|^2dx$

Comment: This is a good point. Even better would be to start with bilinear form $\Psi(x,t)\bar\Psi(x',t')$.

Answer (score 1):

This is physics.  $\Psi$ can have complex values.  So its square need not be positive.

In quantum mechanics the wave function must be complex.  We (so far) have not found how to do it with only real values.

Comment: I never knew that it could also be a complex number. Thanks for clarification

Comment: Isn't $|\Psi(x,t)|^2=\Psi(x,t)\overline{\Psi(x,t)}\geq 0$ i.e. in particular real and can be seen as a probability density as explained e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_function)?